# Execution datetime for SQL queries against SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this nice query I once found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135080/43889).

I'd like to add in the execution time of the queries to the following query:

```
USE master
go

SELECT 
    sdest.DatabaseName, sdes.session_id,
    sdes.[host_name], sdes.[program_name],
    sdes.client_interface_name, 
    sdes.login_name, sdes.login_time,
    sdes.nt_domain, sdes.nt_user_name,
    sdec.client_net_address, sdec.local_net_address,
    sdest.ObjName, sdest.Query
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes
INNER JOIN 
    sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName,
         object_id(objectid) AS ObjName,
         ISNULL((SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                 FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE), '') AS Query
     FROM 
         sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
    ) sdest
WHERE
    sdes.session_id <> @@SPID 
    -- AND sdes.nt_user_name = '' -- Put the username here !
ORDER BY 
    sdec.session_id
```

Is there any column I may not know about that I need to include to get this? Or perhaps another table I need to join too?

Comment: It is by Kin on dba.se http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135080/43889

Comment: awesome, thanks @SqlZim. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of information about query execution based on sql_handle in 
`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`, including:
`last_elapsed_time, max_elapsed_time, total_elapsed_time`

I've added a left join to sys.dm_exec_query_stats and selecting all the fields from it.

```
USE master
go
SELECT sdest.DatabaseName 
    ,sdes.session_id
    ,sdes.[host_name]
    ,sdes.[program_name]
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.login_name
    ,sdes.login_time
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdest.Query
    ,qst.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
    ) sdest

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qst ON qst.sql_handle = sdec.most_recent_sql_handle
WHERE sdes.session_id <> @@SPID 
--and sdes.nt_user_name = '' -- Put the username here !
ORDER BY sdec.session_id
```

Comment: thanks Peter! I think I'm looking for last_execution_time. Do you think last_execution_time reflects the time at which the respective query in the row was executed?

Comment: thanks again, do you know by any chance how far it goes in terms of historical queries? It's strange I have some queries executed on 03-22 and others on 02-23, then others on NULL

Comment: According to MSDN the stats about the query should persist as long as the plan for the query is in the cache. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx . The plan will be removed from the cache after server restarts, by manually clearing it or during memory pressure. Also, the stats about a query is only available for queries which have finished executing.

Comment: I see. I'm a little confused on what a 'plan' is exactly and how it's cached. The purpose with the query above is to get a small history of queries executed against the server. Do you think the query above achieves that purpose?

Comment: A plan, or execution plan, is basically a prepared set of instructions of how to execute a sql query. Because these plans require resources to be calculated, they are cached for re-use. 
This query is suitable for observing information about current and recently executed queries. If you want long term monitoring then I suggest getting a monitoring tool which would collect this kind of information over time.

Comment: right. In essence, I'm trying to create my own monitoring tool so the idea is to execute this query periodically to log the queries that are being executed over time. Do you know if all queries executed against the server are cached for re-use?

Comment: All queries will be cached, but on a machine with heavy memory pressure they might get removed from the cache quickly. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'processing-instruction(definition)' because it contains a character (0x0000) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33811430)